# In OpenGL glTexImage2D() do the last two enums do anything if the 'data' pointer is NULL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'd really like to understand this, but the documentation doesn't make it clear for me. Say I want to write 32-bit integers to a framebuffer, I don't have any pixel data to load to the texture, I'm just creating a framebuffer.

```
void glTexImage2D(  GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLint border,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    const void * data);
```

The documentation implies that the last two enums, format and type are for knowing what type of data the pixel data is that's being read in, and the internalFormat is what's used to know in what format to store the texture that you created.  I thought in cases where you don't provide any texture data the last arguments, or at least one of them aren't used, however I tried changing them to other enum values and I get an error, probably because they were completely wrong enums for that particular argument.

In what cases are the last two enums not used? 
Which one of the three enum values are the ones that decide how the texture is sampled in a shader for example?

Let's just say that I create two example framebuffers.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, NULL);
```

The idea is that I want to write integer values to this framebuffer, so in the fragment shader I do:

```
out int outIntValue

int main()
{
     outIntValue = 7;
     // not 
     // outIntValue.r = 7; 
     right?
}
```

and I sample it like:

```
layout (binding = 0) uniform isampler2D texture1;

int main()
{
    int val = texture(texture1, vec2(0.5, 0.5).r; // .r right?
}
```

In the case of a 32-bit float framebuffer I create it like:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

I write to it like this:

```
out int outFloatValue;

int main()
{
    outFloatValue = 0.7;
    // not
    // outFloatValue.r = 0.7; 

}
```

and sample like this:

```
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texture1;

int main()
{
    float val = texture(texture1, vec2(0.5, 0.5).r; // .r right?
}
```

Also in which of these two cases do the last two enum values do nothing? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your question. I am pretty sure that sampling only depends on the `internalFormat` of the texture and the configuration of the sampler. But yeah, I am still missing the big picture. I also feel like the last two enums should not be needed if the last parameter is `NULL`. Did you try to pass `..., 0, 0, NULL)`? Do you get at an error in that case?

Answer (score 2):

There is one important rule you have to consider related to integral formats:

From [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 8.5 Texture Image Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=225&zoom=100,168,557) (page 215):

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if the internal format is integer and format is not one of the integer formats listed in table 8.3, or if the internal format is not integer and format is an integer format.

The integer formats are for instance `RED_INTEGER`, `RG_INTEGER`, `RGB_INTEGER` ...

Note, in some cases combinations of *internalformat* and *format* generate an error. If no error is generated then it is fine. *format* and *type* do not effect the *internal format* of the target buffer, completely independent on the value of the last parameter (*data*). The only question is do you get an error or not and that can be read in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the texture is filled with data the internal function receives *raw* bytes.

Because each number type (short, int, float, etc) has a different memory representation format, the reading function must know the format to use. It also must know what it's reading (channel RED, or several channels at once, etc).

> In what cases are the last two enums not used?

Never. They are always used.

Comment: The reason I asked was because I'm pretty sure somene told me, maybe here, that at least one of them wasn't used when the pointer was NULL, but I may have been misinformed.

Comment: @Zebrafish When the last parameter to `glTexImage2D` (data) is NULL, then the driver only reserves room for the data, but it doesn't read data from RAM memory.

Comment: Thank you @Ripi2, I always wanted to understand this, it looks like it may happen today. I had exactly the same doubt as Zebrafish for the longest time. You said that the parameters are there because "the reading function must know" and then you said that when the last parameter is NULL then "it doesn't read data". Doesn't this imply that in that case they are not used? Thanks!

Comment: Even assuming that they were stored internally for later use they would need to be specified anew in the next `texImage2D` or `texSubImage2D` call, so I don't think they are stored.

Comment: @damix911 How can the needed size in bytes can be calculated without knowing those parameters?

Comment: I thought that the `internalFormat` alone, together with `width` and `height`, determines the amount of required GPU memory.

Comment: @damix911 I'm refering to the size of data that will be read, not stored.

Comment: But if the last parameter is NULL there is nothing to read.

If `format` and `type` were used for such calculation, why does also `glTexSubImage2D` have them?

Comment: @damix911 Because `gl..Sub..` may read **part** of the total data.

Comment: But nothing can be read if the last parameter is NULL. How are `format` and `type` useful in that case?

Answer (score 1):

> In what cases are the last two enums not used?

From the OpenGL 4.6 (Core Profile) - October 22, 2019, page 203.

```
format, type, and data specify the format of
the image data, the type of those data, and a reference to the image data in the 
currently bound pixel unpack buffer or client memory, as described in section
```

It looks like they are not *"used"* if `data` is `NULL`, but they are always checked against the `internalFormat` and you get an error if you specify an illegal combination. I guess this is the best you can do in a C API.

> Which one of the three enum values are the ones that decide how the texture is sampled in a shader for example?

Only `internalFormat` and the sampling configuration count from the perspective of shaders.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, done. What I wanted to say is that it appears that there are multiple ways to set those two params (and there are even more in 4.6 than WebGL 2, where it is my understanding that some of those restrictions are lifted) and ultimately it does not matter when `data` is `NULL`. I would have rather forced the user to use special values such as `GL_UNUSED` or `0` in the no-data case, than allow them to specify almost anything. At least that would make it clear that they are irrelevant. But I guess I am nitpicking.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for finding out for me. Yes, I was at the point of wondering what arguments I should pass for the last two enums if I'm not sending image pixel data, because I wanted the function call to be clear as opposed to just putting GL_RED_INTEGER and GL_INT

Comment: You are welcome! I think you asked a good question. I found the docs confusing and also another dev that I know had similar doubts about that API.